# Is it legal for a stock broker to use client's idle money to generate interest and enjoy the benefit without sharing it with its clients?

Tags: united-states, stocks, brokerage, broker

I read an "investment report" about an online US stock broker, saying that the broker can gain extra earnings from clients' idle money interest without sharing the interest with its clients.

Is that legal and possible?

Comment: If you the brokerage say “sweep account yields 1.25%” but put the money in a “bank account” which earns 2%, then you get to keep the extra 0.75%.  I wouldn’t be shocked or upset at that.

Comment: That's basically how money market funds work, in a nutshell

Comment: It's also how banks work. What protects the depositor is that the banks are required to carry insurance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it legal? Yes. This is called "making a profit". The basic principle behind it is how every business in a free market works: You buy something for $X and then you resell it to a customer for $X+something. The difference is your gross profit, from which you pay your expenses, pay your employees, and if you're lucky have something left over for yourself.

Banks are in the business of loaning money. So they borrow money for some low interest rate and then loan it out at a higher interest rate. The difference is called the "spread".

Stock brokers used to make money by charging their clients a fee for each trade. But with the arrival of discount brokers, those fees have been whittled down to somewhere between peanuts and zero. So how to make money today? One way is to invest the cash balance in a client's account and keep all or most of the profits on that. This is called "float". A client deposits, say, $1000 in his account, and then a couple of days later he uses that $1000 to buy a stock. In those few days the broker can invest or loan the $1000 and make a little money. If the client leaves a little spare cash for a long period, the broker can make more from it. That's typically not a lot per client but if your clients are mostly self-directing trades on the Internet then your costs per client are low. And if you have many many clients, making a few dollars a year from each one adds up.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I thought the cash should be *quarantined*  in a safe that no one except the client could use.

Comment: @AGamePlayer (1) Why did you think that?  (2) The client **can** use it whenever they want.  (3) Money is fungible. (4) You don’t send them cash; you send them computer bits that *represent money*.  (5) Brokerages and banks are not lawyers which need to put your money in an escrow account.  Even then, it’s not cash.  (6) Brokerages would need a heck of a lot of safes!  And who would organize them?

Comment: @RonJohn Thanks for the reply. I am a bit new to this idea. And my broker told me that they would never use my money to do anything about investment. They send me interest if I have cash in my account, and I guess the interest is just part of what they earn from that money. But that's okay, I'm find with that. I just want to know whether this is ordinary.

Comment: @AGamePlayer Many people have the same thought about banks. They think when they deposit money, the bank puts it in an envelope with their name on it and stores it in the vault (or something equivalent). In reality, the bank loans the money out. That's how a bank makes money. If your broker really kept any cash you gave him in a safe, how would he earn a living? He would have to charge you a fee for his services one way or another. ...

Comment: ... Personally, I find it less painful to say that the broker can pay with the cash I give him but has to give it back when I ask for it, i.e. he gets free use of my money, rather than he charges me a fee. I suppose the net effect is the same. If the broker had to pay me interest on money I deposit with him, and then I had to pay him a fee that, on average, was the same as the interest, we'd end up in the same place. But emotionally, paying the fee FEELS worse. :-)

Comment: @AGamePlayer "they would never use my money to do anything **about investment**."  Right.  *Investing* your *spare money* is a Big Fat No-No in the US.  That (crypto-"currency" exchange FTX sending people's spare money to hedge fund Alameda Research) is part of what got Sam Bankman-Fried into so much trouble.

Comment: @AGamePlayer but _real_ brokerages don't send your spare money to hedge funds: they send it in bulk to FDIC-insured bank accounts.

Comment: @RonJohn is there any public channels to investigate whether a broker send my spare money to hedge funds? (in my case, the broker is a US-listed one)

Comment: @AGamePlayer good question.  The answer to what a broker does with client money is probably in some SEC filing.

Comment: @AGamePlayer honest brokers, though, will **tell you** where the money goes.  For example, Vanguard’s settlement fund VMFXX has a prospectus which specifies what they buy.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Do I have to find it out on my own or is there any list on the web to show the honest brokers?

Comment: @RonJohn IMHO, an honest business will tell you about how they make money if asked. But the fact that a business fails to volunteer all sorts of details of all their operations when I first walk in the door ... I wouldn't call that "dishonest". I'd mostly call that not wasting everyone's time with information that most people won't care about. Like I used to work for a company that rented the upstairs of a small store for office space. I don't suppose that every time someone walked in that store the clerk said, "We should tell you that in addition to making money by selling ...

Comment: ... merchandise we also make money by renting unused space to another company." Who would care? Likewise, what my stock broker does with money I deposit with him, I just don't much care, as long as he's able to give it back when I ask for it. I don't consider it "dishonest" for him to make some money off of cash I have parked with him. Frankly I'd rather if he did make money that way rather than charging me higher fees.

Comment: @Jay the store analogy is not applicable, and the managed funds broker **must** tell you where your money is (on your monthly/quarterly statement) if they're following FINRA regulations.  And each fund must have a prospectus.

Comment: @AGamePlayer any FINRA-registered broker is Good Enough.  You can't go wrong with big self-service brokers like (alphabetically) Fidelity, Schwab and Vanguard.

Comment: Are there even non-FINRA-registered brokers... Just wondering. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @RonJohn Hmm, my statements from my brokers all say "Cash .... $500" or whatever number. I don't think they say whether the broker has that money in green paper in an envelope in a safe, in a bank account with a ledger entry somewhere saying how much belongs to each client, or in a money market account or what. Maybe it's in the fine print somewhere.

Comment: @Jay "Maybe it's in the fine print somewhere."  Probably so.  (I haven't used a full-service broker in 30 years, so don't remember.  Fidelity, Schwab and Vanguard have money market sweep accounts / settlement funds and Voya has a money market and NY Life Guarantee fund for cash.)